# Number and letter numbering of tables in word with cross-referencing

Tags: ms-word, seq

How do I get a smart numbering system as shown below? Whenever I have a new table, I want the numbering to rise.
If, on the other hand, I add a row to the table, I would like to add a letter in behind the numbering.
Is this possible?

[image: Picture showing the idea behind the numbering]

I have startet using Field Codes and Sequences, and I believe it is the way to go.

I know the numbering without the letters can be obtained by

```
Number #{ STYLEREF 1\s}{SEQ Table \# "00"}
```

I also know that alphabetic numbering can be made by using the \alphabetic command.

I am just not sure how to combine them. Also, I would like to make cross-references to the table captions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with Word's built-in numbering - no need to resort to a complex combination of fields that you'll need to manually update.

I'm going to outline the very complete approach...

1. On the Home tab: Paragraph/Multilevel list/Define new list style.
2. Enter a name for the style, then from the Format button choose Numbering; click More.
3. With Level 1 selected, choose the style with which you want to link the numbering (Heading 1, for example)
4. In the "Enter formatting for number" field type any text you want to have appear before or after every number. (According to your picture: Header in front of the number 1 with grey shading already in the box.)
5. Select Level 2, choose the style with which you want to link the numbering (Heading 2, for example)
6. In the "Enter formatting for number" field type in front of the number (2, grey shading): Number #00
7. From the "Include level number from" dropdown, select level 1. The number from Level 1 will be inserted between the last 0 and the grey-shaded 2.
8. If necessary, change the alignment settings (you probably don't want the indent inside the table cell?)

Now, when you apply the Heading styles the numbering will be applied automatically. If you don't like the formatting of the Heading styles you can change the style definition(s). Since you created a numbering style, you can also change these settings by going again to the Multilevel numbering dialog box, right-clicking the numbering format you created and selecting "Modify".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have just uploaded another illustration to the topic, as the former did you show the idea entirely.
1. It should initially start with the chapter number
2. The numbering should be of the format 01, 02, etc.
3. In case a table contains more than more row, it will be because multiple rows are part of the same condition. In this case I will need a subnumbering in the form of a, b, c, etc.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't see that ability in Word's automatically build in numbering.

Comment: I believe this solution works. By remembering to add a space after the numbering I am also able to cross-reference the numbering.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you - automatic numbering, when it works, does make life much easier for cross-referencing, etc. If you have a moment to activate the checkmark for the answer to your question that will help others searching the site with similar issues to recognize which suggestion(s) were helpful :-)

Comment: Additional question:
Is it possible with the multilevel list to have a formatting that spans multiple lines?
E.g.

Numbers <br\>
#1001a, 

Numbers <br\>
#1001b, etc.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I tried entering a Shift+Enter character (new line), which the dialog box accepts, but it inserts a symbol instead of the break. It doesn't accept a new paragraph at all.

Comment: I have created a multilevel list for the table numbering. However, now it messes up my header numbering when I use the 'Link level to style' option for the first level of the table numbering. If I refer to header 1, my header level 2 looses its reference to header 1.
Shouldn't it be possible to make a reference to a headline without changing the headline?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how you have things structured. However, it is possible for you to use different (lower) heading levels for the table stuff than for other headings in the document. Table heading numbers can start with Level 5, for example. Use the options in the dialog box so that this level is NOT dependent on higher levels for its numbering (the Restart after level one).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following field code approach will give you the numbering indicated in your sample image (where the table numbering restarts for each Heading 1 paragraph. However, it will probably only work for "in-line" tables, not floating tables or tables in text boxes and so on.

The main aim here is to ensure can insert exactly the same field codes for each new "Number#" that you need, but to achieve that you also have to put some codes at the beginning and end of each table. You will also need to select and re-execute all the field codes *twice* to ensure that they are updated properly - this is the kind of disadvantage that Cindy Meister's Answer mentions.

At or before the beginning of each table, put the following fields. (If you are already putting a table caption *before* each table, you could do this slightly differently.)

```
{ SEQ tbl \s 1 \h }{ SEQ ltr \r0 \h }
```

This increments the table number, resetting at each Heading 1 paragraph, and resets the letter number to 0.

For every "Number #" you want in a table, use the following fields:

```
Number #{ STYLEREF 1 \s }{ SEQ tbl \c #00 }{ SEQ ltr \h }{ IF { REF "chap{ STYLEREF 1 \s }tbl{ SEQ tbl \c }" } > 1 "{ SEQ ltr \c \*alphabetic }" "" }
```

This inserts the appropriate Heading number and the table number, and increments the letter number. It then looks at a bookmark that contains the number of "Number #" entries in this table. For example, if Heading 1 is numbered 4, and this is the thrid table under that heading, the bookmark will be called "chap1tbl4". If the bookmark's value is greater than 1, the appropriate letter will be appended.

But we have to create that bookmark and value, which we can only do after all the "Number #" fields for that table. So at the end of each table, or immediately after the table and before any new Heading 1 paragraph, you will need the following field codes:

{ SET "chap{ STYLEREF 1 \s }tbl{ SEQ tbl \c }" { SEQ ltr \c } }

The thing is that Word evaluates field codes in the sequence they appear in the document. So when Word first encounters the { REF } field in the table, the bookmark will have no value. So the first time you select all the fields and execute them, you may see the wrong answer. After you have done that, the bookmark is created. Word will use the value most recently assigned to the bookmark, so the next time you execute the "Number #" fields, they should work properly.

I *think* to achieve what you wanted using the general approach given in Cindy Meister's Answer, you would need to have two separate Heading levels, one for the Numbers without letters,and another for the numbers with letters. The user, or some VBA (say) would then have to decide for each table which Heading level to use. But even if that is the case (and she may have something else in mind), it may still be an operationally simpler approach than the field-based one. I suspect only you are in a position to decide.

There may be a simpler field-based formulation, but IME the basic problem is that you cannot test the "final value" of a SEQ or SET field, only the value it has at the point of execution. For example, if there was a \f flag that let you test the final value of a SEQ field, you could use

```
{ IF { SEQ "chap{ STYLEREF 1 \s }tbl{ SEQ tbl \c }" \f } > 1 .... }
```

to test the number of "Number #" entries in each table, without having to have that awkward end-of-table SET field.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work (almost).

Using the { SEQ tbl \c} provides me with the correct numbering, but at the loss of the "00" format.
I know I can use { SEQ tbl \#"00"} and get the right numbering format. I have also tried { SEQ tbl \c"00"}, but that does not work.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: And secondly. How do I make a cross-reference to the entire caption?

Comment: For your first question, the field code I provided already uses { SEQ tbl \#00 }. It seems to work OK here. What doesn't work there? (Incidentally, the { SEQ tbl \c } in the bookmark name does not need the \#00, although you can include it everywhere SEQ tbl \c } is used if you want. I would not expect { SEQ tbl \c"00" } to help.

Comment: For your second question, IMO you should modify your Question to specify that you need to cross-reference these things. it's certain that with this approach you won't be able to use the built-in cross-referencing mechanism, because it relies on finding either auto-numbering paragraphs (as per Cindy Meister's response) or specific field code patterns. Attempting to generate bookmarks for each Number # would not typically help, so either you have to insert bookmarks where you need them and reference those, or build your own VBA dialog that detects and references your own Number # scheme.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the feedback. I have now changed the header and question slightly to include the cross-reference issue.
As I feared, it looks as if only a very complicated solution would work.