# Multilevel list skip numbering

Tags: ms-word, multi-level, numbered-list

I have created a multilevel list for being able to reference to table rows in a word document. [Multilevel list thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695281/number-and-letter-numbering-of-tables-in-word-with-cross-referencing/33697656?noredirect=1#comment55514602_33697656)

With the multilevel list I struggle to skip numbers. The table numbering is divided into two levels. NNN and NNNL, where N: Number and L:Letter.

*Example:*

```
    1. Header 1
       101
       101a
    2. Header 2
       201a
```

The numbering below header 1 works fine, but header 2 does NOT work.

The numbering are used for clauses in a document, so in case a clause is divided into different conditions, the class NNNL is used. However, as it is now, it needs the NNN for create NNNL.

I have tried using 'Set numbering value' - 'Continue from previous list' - 'Advance value (skip numbers)', following this [solution suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/496129/word-will-not-set-the-numbering-value-that-i-choose), but following this guide still results in the addition of a level NNN before (see below for examplification).

```
    2. Header 2
      201 <- This is added
      201a
```

Can't I skip a numbering value of a list level above the item I wish to change?

*Edited*:
Also, when having a subheader I face issues. If the first clause after a subheader is divided into subclauses, I get

```
     101
    1.1 subheader
     101a
```

What I want is this

```
     101
    1.1 subheader
     102a
```

I have uploaded a word-file I have uploaded a word-document [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GG7gvM7ptVXjHFy5xlrQXaW187PsOGNz1f6Yk-Y7MV0/edit?usp=sharing) which shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set both Level 2 and Level 3 to restart after Level 1 (in the dialog box described in the Answer of first post to which you link). This way you can leave out Level 2 and Level 3 will still restart.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the suggestion. If I have a subheader, I cannot get it to work. Lets say I have: <br/>
#101, #102...
When having a new subparagraph it would start with #102a, #102b, etc.
What I want it to do is to be #103a, #103b, etc.
I have tried to set level 2 to restart after Heading 2 level.

Comment: It would help us help you if your samples were more thorough and covered all the possibilities. We can only answer based on the information you provide. You should EDIT your original question to include ALL relevant requirements.